# Existing AR products to implement "markerless" Augmented Reality

Tags: ios, 3d, augmented-reality

FACTS

I need to develop an iPhone App that should be able to look at an empty room and place 3d objects into it (furniture). I don't mind walls of the room, in theory you could use it in open space too. Only needed thing is the ability to correctly place objects on the "floor" and to look around them.

QUESTION

Do you know any existing AR library for iOS that can do that? I don't want to use pre-printed images or similar. The library must be able to recognize movement of the device and to place camera (compute view matrix) accordingly without any external marker. I tried to do it by myself using CoreMotion but i just wasn't able to implement it (even if i know well 3d math and physics). I'm willing to pay for the product if there's no free alternative.